# Share with facebook sdk using non activity class

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

first of all I would like to clarify that I'm new at this.
I am trying to implement facebook sdk to let users share pictures and so on of my app. I am following this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share but I have a problem. I'm working with fragments so I can't override onResume() method, I can't implement setOnCompleteListener, I can't get the Bundle savedInstanceState, etc. Can anybody give me a hint of how to deal with this? I would appreciate it. Thanxs a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try coding the facebook integration from a base Activity and call the relevant methods of facebook login, picture share from the Fragment by means of intent to the activity and also make sure to finish the facebook share Activity once the picture share is over.